# Adding Delay in application (for debugging)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'd like to add a delay between 2 lines of code because I'm testing an updateprogress template. Ideally, the one-liner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method. Example:

```
Thread.Sleep(3000); //3 seconds
```

You will need to add this using directive:

```
using System.Threading;
```

to get access to the method.

The parameter you pass it is the number of milliseconds you want to suspend the current thread.

Comment: ouch the 30 chars limit skrewed me again ^^

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method and [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

```
#if DEBUG
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx). It takes the time to sleep in milliseconds

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);//Waits 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [Thread.Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could put that line in a condition, that will only be 'true', passing that amount of time, using the delay method: Thread.Sleep(time)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int time_ms); //One line, no 'using' :)
```